# ngModelChange doesn't fire when ngModel is changed from the component without user input

Tags: angular

I have a directive that should update some internal value based on input's ngModel. This works fine when user types values in manually, but stops working when ngModel is changed from the component.

Component template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myValue" myExample>
```

Changing ngModel in component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getDataFromApi()
  .then((result) => {
    this.myValue = result;
  })
}
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myExample][ngModel]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(ngModelChange)' : 'onModelChange($event)',
  }
})
export class myExampleDirective implements OnInit {
  private _valueInDirective;

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _model: NgModel) { }

  onModelChange(event) {
    this._valueInDirective = event;
  }
}
```

If the ngModel is updated from controller after an API call, ngModelChange in directive doesn't fire and the _valueInDirective is not updated. How to make sure that every time the ngModel is updated, value in directive will be changed as well?

Comment: and it is not supposed to. `ngModelChange` is only emitted when the inputs elements value changes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, but after ngModel changes, the input element's value changes as well, right?

Comment: When change detection for `[ngModel]="myValue"` detects that `myValue` changed, then it will update the `ngModel` property. Angular doesn't observe random fields for changes, it only observes bindings. `(ngModelChange)` (the `()` part  of `[(ngModel)]`) is **only** called when the `NgModel` directive calls `this.ngModelChange.next(someValue)`

Comment: This is not really helpful. I still don't know why doesn't it fire when clearly the value did change.

Comment: Because it's just intentionally designed to not do that, and I don't see a need. It basically would just cause an endless loop if it did. What are your actually trying to accomplish? You can just call `ngModelChange(...);` yourself when you change the value.

Comment: I don't think it would cause an endless loop. You can still compare new value with prev value and fire only if actual change happened. And obviously, I can't call anything from the directive until it gets to know that the model changed. I have found however that I can subscribe to model changes, and this way directive will get notified about them.

Comment: Angular is all about efficiency, and that kind of stuff is the exact opposite of efficient. That's what AngularJS does and why they build a new different Angular to not repeat the mistakes of the past. It's called unidirectional data-flow which avoids that kind of cycles instead of detecting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experimented with `DoCheck` hook, but it turned out extremely inefficient. This is the solution I ended up with and I'm happy with:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myExample][ngModel]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class myExampleDirective implements OnInit {
  private _valueInDirective;

  constructor(private _model: NgModel) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._model.valueChanges.subscribe((event) => {
      this._valueInDirective = event;
      // do other stuff
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem to call a method yourself when you change the value? You can also make the field you bind to a getter/setter and call additional code in the setter.

Comment: Because I change the value in the controller, and need to call a method in directive. I am repeating this information the third time.

Comment: Looks like a workaround, I'm disappointed that it cannot fire ``@HostListener('ngModelChange')`` ! But still, it's working